# JavaFx8 Properties Binding causing "No Fx8 Application thread"

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-8

my program isn't working as i want. I wrote a class called "`Uhr`", which is a simple timer. To display the timer, i also wrote a class called "`UhrMain`", which should create a GUI. Everything is working perfect, but whenever my `StringProperty` is changed in the class "`Uhr`", i am getting a "`No Fx8 Application thread`"-error. So the label isn't getting updated.

To bind the time to the label, i used this code:

```
timeLabel.textProperty().bind(eineUhr.zeitProperty());
```

I have absolutely no clue why this isnt working.

Uhr.java:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package uhr;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Uhr extends Thread{

    private final StringProperty zeit;
    private int mSec;
    private int sec;
    private boolean running;

    public Uhr(){
        zeit = new SimpleStringProperty();
        running = false;
    }

    public final StringProperty zeitProperty(){
        return zeit;
    }

    public final String getZeit(){
        return zeit.get();
    }

    public synchronized void startTimer(){
        this.running = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stopTimer(){
        this.running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                mSec++;
                if(mSec >= 10){
                    mSec = 0;
                    sec++;
                    zeit.set("Zeit: " + sec);
                    System.out.println(zeit.get());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Uhr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

MainTest.java

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package uhr;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class UhrMain extends Application {

    private VBox box;
    private Button startButton;
    private Button stopButton;
    private Label timeLabel;
    private Uhr eineUhr;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        eineUhr = new Uhr();
        eineUhr.start();
        box = new VBox();
        timeLabel = new Label("Zeit: ");
        startButton = new Button("Start");
        //startButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
        startButton.setOnAction((event) -> eineUhr.startTimer());
        stopButton = new Button("Stopp");
        //stopButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
        stopButton.setOnAction((event) -> eineUhr.stopTimer());
        box.getChildren().addAll(timeLabel,startButton,stopButton);
        timeLabel.textProperty().bind(eineUhr.zeitProperty());
        Scene scene = new Scene(box);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Stoppuhr");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: please note that `running` is never used in your code, it is only set nothing more

Comment: yes thanks for mentioning, already noticed that. I thought this would cause the problem, so i temporary deleted the operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method should be changed:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    while(true){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            mSec++;
            if(mSec >= 10){
                mSec = 0;
                sec++;
                Platform.runLater(()->zeit.set("Zeit: " + sec));
                System.out.println(zeit.get());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Uhr.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

it fixed the crash for me.

Comment: Already tried this in my start method, but it isnt working correctly. Whenever i resize my window after starting the application, the time label is getting updated once and no more.

Comment: I've changed my answer. In should help.

Comment: But can you explain why i need to do that? The Bindings normally work without the Platform.runLater, no?

Comment: Because all changes with UI should be done in the main thread. Using Platform.runLater() you put your code to the queue of the main thread and when app has some time for it, your code will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the `set` method calls on your `StringProperty`'s instance into a [`Platform.runLater(Runnable runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) to prevent this issue by ensuring that it is modified through the `JavaFX Application Thread` as next, indeed calling `set` will have a direct impact on your UI as it is bound and only the `JavaFX Application Thread` is allowed to modify your UI since the `Java FX Components` are not thread safe.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> zeit.set("Zeit: " + sec));
```

Comment: Was just about to write the same answer. The changes to the StringProperty has to be done on the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used JavaFX in a while, but I think you just need to run any UI related stuff in the correct UI Thread (like most UI Frameworks there can only be one Thread to access the UI elements).

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    timeLabel.textProperty().bind(eineUhr.zeitProperty());   
  }
});
```